Convert entire media library to WebP, delete original images and update references
I am in the process of revamping an existing site. The process I wish to follow is to start with a new clean site, then export/import posts and images in batches from the old site to the new. In the process, I wish to convert all the images to WebP format, so that the new site stores only WebP images. How can I do this in an efficient manner?

There are a lot of Paid Plugins for that and also you can use online Free Resource for that, but not all of them allow the Batch Process. Although I have use JPG To Webp for image compression. You can try if it helps you, although If you have good budget then try some PRO Plugins.
